# Problem with a matrix

Tags: lists, matrices

I have to write a matrix, my code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document} 
\begin{itemize}
\item Esercizio 165 
$\begin{matrix}
1  &   h\\
 h & -1\\
1  & -1
\end{matrix}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I obtain:

```
 ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.13 1  &
            h\\
?
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to load the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package which provides the `matrix` environment:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

---

If you—for some inhumane reason—can’t use the `amsmath` package, the `\matrix` *macro* (which will raise an error if used with the `amsmath` package loaded) uses the syntax

```
$\matrix{
  1  &  h \crcr
   h & -1 \crcr
  1  & -1}$
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
$\begin{array}{cc}
1  &   h\\
 h & -1\\
1  & -1
\end{array}$
```

`cc` means that the matrix (array) has two centered colums. Another posibilities: `l` - left, `r` - right.